# Execute a SP or start an sql job upon restore compleion

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016, database-restore

I'm wondering if there is an option to start an SQL job or exec a stored procedure once *ANY* database has been restored/finished restoring? I tried to create an `INSERT` trigger for **msdb.restorehistory** but apparently it only works when I manually insert values into that table (which is undesired and not a good idea anyway).

Using SQL server 2016.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17103/automatically-execute-stored-procedure-after-any-restore-database-event

Comment: `CREATE EVENT NOTIFICATION ... FOR AUDIT_BACKUP_RESTORE_EVENT`. `EventSubClass` 2 is a restore event. Getting event notifications up and running is a bit fiddly because you'll need to read up on how to do service broker queues with activation as well, but it's worth the time investment.

Comment: Deffo worth a look. However its a bit of a shame that even in 2017 you have to play with such workarounds to get a simple thing done.